# Nginx Rewrites for Custom PHP Framework

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php, rewrite

I'm moving a custom mvc php app into production on ubuntu & nginx, and have been struggling with the rewrite structure for the app.  The goal is taking controller oriented urls like this:

```
    domain.com/index.php?controller=store&action=search&category=3
```

and turning them into visually pleasing urls like this

```
    domain.com/store/search/category/3
```

Like other frameworks, the app runs all requests through an index.php file, which searches for the appropriate controller to handle the request. To handle this I've added an initial rewrite rule like so:

```
    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }
```

In the rewrite module I have:

```
    location @rewrite {

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?op=$1 last;   }
```

The above code is a start on getting me closer to accessing our controllers via cleaner urls, but I'm no closer to a larger strategy to deal with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've scoured most of the web and the resources I come across seem to be too vague, too specific, or outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) has an example that helps directly with your problem:

> Syntax:    `rewrite regex replacement [flag];`
>
> But if these directives are put inside the `/download/` location, the
>   `last` flag should be replaced by `break`, or otherwise nginx will make 10
>   cycles and return the 500 error:
>
> ```
> location /download/ {
>     rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 break;
>     rewrite ^(/download/.*)/audio/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.ra  break;
>     return  403;
> }
> ```

We need to modify `/index.php?controller=store&action=search&category=3` to the correct form for `replacement` string, get the variables from `/store/search/category/3` by turning it into a `regex` and remember to use `break` inside `location`.

- If all the four parts are variables:

  ```
  rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&$3=$4 break;
  ```
- If the `category` is a fixed part of the URL:

  ```
  rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/category/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&category=$3 break;
  ```

Comment: Hi Esa, 
Thanks for the response. A follow up: With the structure of our app (index.php -> controllers), should I be using location /index.php {} with the above recommendations?

Comment: They are for `location /` (or your `location @rewrite`). I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but you can't use them on `location` that matches the `replacement`, but on the side before the substitution.

Comment: Thank you Esa, this is helpful. If you're willing, I have one more question. With .htaccess mod_rewrite, we are able to add keywords (name of category for example) to our urls with something like this:

        RewriteRule ^categories/(\d+)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=default&action=category&id=$1

The equivalment in nginx doesn't seem to work the same. For example, if we use in nginx:

        rewrite ^/categories/(\d+)/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=default&action=category&id=$1 last;

Category names aren't added. Is there another directive required for this behavior on nginx?

Comment: Could you give an example of such url and how it gets rewritten by Apache and not by Nginx? Actually, with all these speficications it would be better to ask a new question. Notice that temporarily using Apache flag `R` and Nginx flag `redirect` (external HTTP redirect) you could debug this as you get to see the resulting rewrite of every URL.

Comment: This was a simple syntax error. If you have the above code working in apache, it will work in nginx as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, if the suggestions in my answer have any errors or problems, feel free to correct them to be more useful for others.